# "Search by" after import an Excel file

Tags: android, excel

I am developing a project which consists on importing a file from an external storage and then my goal it's "Search by".

I have to public classes, one of them will controll the database and the second one is the MainActivity.

My output after importing the .csv file is:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bNL0d.png)

That EditText field is where I want to for example right "Apple" and my select query will show me just the Apple products by Company.

```html
EditText etSearch = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etSearch);

        etSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                controller = new DBController(getApplicationContext());
                SQLiteDatabase db = controller.getWritableDatabase();
                String tableName = "proinfo";
                db.execSQL("SELECT Company FROM " + tableName);
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a OnTextChangedListener to the EditText and write your search query inside that method. Populate your ListView based on the search result.

Comment: OnTextChangedListener will trigger everytime you change text of your edittext. Since you will have new content in your edittext then you can search the imported data for the elements that match the string and show only the relevant ones.

Comment: See the code that I added, it is something like that?

Comment: But that gave me some erros, what can I do?

Comment: SELECT Company FROM " + tableName + " WHERE <companyname> like " + s.getText() + "%" .. Change the query to this and move it from Ontextchanged to aftertextchanged

Comment: But I add that on DBController or MainActivity? @Anshul

Comment: I am not sure how you are designing things.  You need the ability to search your excel content either by storing it in a dB or in a datastructure and the filter out the ones that match the edit text content. Figure out a way to be able to search your data based on some text

Comment: What can I do to help you figure out a solution? @Anshul

Comment: Read up on Android data handling and list views then you can use the code above.  You will have to do the heavy lifting yourself